# Can't install lxml on python 3.5

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, lxml

I searched for solution to my problem through this and other sites. Unfortunately, none of given solutions helped me.

My problem is the following. I'd like to install python lxml library but every time I get errors.

1) When I try install lxml in pycharm , I get the follwoing error:

```
ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external      command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
```

2) When I try install lxml in command line with pip install lxml, I get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install lxml
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files\python35\python.exe" -u -c "i
mport setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\forucell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
pip-build-cwlxrbh_\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:
\Users\forucell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vx4433si-record\install-record.txt --sing
le-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.6.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *
*

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\includ
es
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\html
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\i
soschematron
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml
    copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\include
s
    copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\inclu
des
    copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\in
cludes
    copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\inc
ludes
    copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\includ
es
    copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\inc
ludes
    copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\inclu
des
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\inclu
des
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\incl
udes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\incl
udes
    copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\includes

    copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\includes
    copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\inclu
des
    copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\inc
ludes
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib
.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win
-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win
-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schema
tron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstra
ct_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-sc
hematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_i
nclude.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schem
atron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schema
tron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso
-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schema
tron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resour
ces\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_f
or_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-sch
ematron-xslt1
    copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt
 -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt
1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\lxml
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /
nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc\lxml\includes "-Ic:\program files\python35
\include" "-Ic:\program files\python35\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micros
oft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual St
udio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\1
0.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\
um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8
.1\include\\winrt" /Tcsrc\lxml\lxml.etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\
src\lxml\lxml.etree.obj -w
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
    lxml.etree.c
    src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include f
ile: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
    Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14
.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    creating Users
    creating Users\forucell
    creating Users\forucell\AppData
    creating Users\forucell\AppData\Local
    creating Users\forucell\AppData\Local\Temp
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /
nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Vi
sual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\in
clude\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\i
nclude\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /TcC:\Users\forucell\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit2v
eo73kj.c /FoUsers\forucell\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit2veo73kj.obj
    xmlXPathInit2veo73kj.c
    C:\Users\forucell\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit2veo73kj.c(1): fatal error
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
    ****************************************************************************
*****
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 insta
lled?
    ****************************************************************************
*****
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python35\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokeni
ze;__file__='C:\\Users\\forucell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-cwlxrbh_\\lxml
\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replac
e('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\forucell\AppData\
Local\Temp\pip-vx4433si-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-ma
naged --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\forucell\AppData\Local\Tem
p\pip-build-cwlxrbh_\lxml\
```

3) When I try install lxml in whl format, I get the follwoing error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 21
5, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", li
ne 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 74
2, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 346, in
move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 317, in
clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line
 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\Li
b\\site-packages\\lxml
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to install a compiler first (may be VS C++ express) and install it with pip `set STATICBUILD=true && pip install lxml`. Check version of `pip` first. to know pip for python 2 or 3.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a prepackaged [wheel for lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

Comment: I tried but got the above error.
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\Li
b\\site-packages\\lxml

Comment: julivico,  I am a new at Python. However, I have managed errors so far. But this is so though.

I installed MS VS 14.0. I gave a path of vcvarsall to msvc9compiler.py as vcvarsall="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC"+"/vcvarsall.bat".

Did I do right?  So what should I do next. Please guide me.

Comment: 1.When I tried to install any downloaded whl package, I get    PermissionError: [winError 5]. 2. When I tried ti did with administrator acces in cmd, the file was not found. P.S> package was psutil just for example.

Comment: Lol. Finally I solved my problem. I reinstalled python into C: directory from C:/Program Files. This gave me permission to install .whl files from cmd.

Answer (score 2):

`lxml` needs C/C++ libraries `libxml`, `libxstl` so you have to install it first. But they are not Python modules but standard libraries - probably `libxml.dll`, `libxstl.dll.`

`lxml` may need also source code for this libraries or C/C++ header files *.h and C/C++ compiler to compile `lxml`

For Windows exists [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) with precompiled modules and there is lxml

> NOTE:It maybe a duplicate question.you can see this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641916/failing-to-load-packages-with-pycharm)

Answer (score -3):

You need to update your `pip`. If the version is 7.0.3, run command:

`py -m pip install --upgrade pip` on Command Prompt. Try again

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem occurs even with up-to-date pip.