# lxml is not installing in pycharm ide

Tags: python, pycharm

lxml not installing in pycharm ide.
this code is not running due to lxml is not installed. How to install lxml package in pycharm

```
page = urlopen(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
print(soup.title)

  [Erro while edding lxml code in pycharm][1]
```

Answer (score 6):

To install a new package directly in PyCharm, you can go to

Settings->Project->Project Interpreter.

After this you should see the interpreter that PyCharm uses to run your project.

If you don't see **lxml** in the package's table, you can press the **plus icon** in the right corner of the window and type **lxml** and proceed with the installation.

Let me know

Comment: It would be a good answer for almost any other python library, but not `lxml` (e.g see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653018/cant-install-lxml-on-python-3-5) why)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing an older version (in my case, version 4.9.0) through the venv terminal.

```
pip install lxml==4.9.0
```

Has worked for me on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with PyCharm 2022.2.3, but probably shouldn't be used as a permanent fix.