# Failing to load packages with pycharm

Tags: python, xslt, pycharm, lxml

I am trying to do some web scraping using python with PyCharm on a windows 10 machine. Some sites suggest using lxml library and it sounds good. I am trying to load the package but am having trouble. What should I do?

OK great. I go to add lxml 3.6.4 in the package installer and it fails with the message(s):

```
ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
```

and

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
```

I installed libxml2dom via the package installer but that does not do the trick

xslt-config is not one of the available packages in the available packages installer
libxml2 is also not an available package

I do not see "libxml2" from the options of available packages.  But I do see "libxml2-python" 2.6.21
I tried to install it, but it fails with the message:

```
Collecting libxml2-python==2.6.21
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2-python==2.6.21 (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for libxml2-python==2.6.21
```

I have been able to load other packages
Using python interpreter 3.5.2
Using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3

Comment: I would suggest to use scrapy package (https://scrapy.org/) for scraping websites. Installing package through pip install scrapy will install all required packages for scraping including libxml (not libxml2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lxml` needs C/C++ libraries `libxml`, `libxstl` so you have to install it first. But they are not Python modules but standard libraries - probably `libxml.dll`, `libxstl.dll`.

`lxml` may need also source code for this libraries or C/C++ header files `*.h` and C/C++ compiler to compile `lxml`

For Windows exists [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) with precompiled modules and there is `lxml`

But much easier (for Windows user) is use [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which installs the same Python from Python.org but with extra, precompiled modules like `lxml`. See [list of modules](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs).

PyCharm can use different Python with different project so you can have installed current Python and Anaconda and use them both in PyCharm.